# how to set up a static website on a domain?

Tags: php, dns

I want the url http://welcome.com (for example) to render the content from the url http://www.cleaning.com/welcome without redirecting to cleaning.com.

so when people go to welcome.com they see the content from http://www.cleaning.com/welcome but welcome.com remains in the address bar. how can I do that?

Comment: That's domain aliasing, I believe. Dreamhost calls it [server aliasing](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mirror_Domain) or mirroring.

Comment: Have fun watching your site get dropped from Google

Comment: Do you have cpanel - would be easier to setup with. Why would you even want this to happen anyway, if you REALLY want the content in http://www.cleaning.com/welcome on your http://welcome.com page just copy the content onto your page - why complicate things? Lastly you will be punished by google for doing this.

Comment: I think you should listen to @JohnConde: [Almost all search engines will blacklist your domain if they find the exact same content at another domain.](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mirror_Domain#Reason_To_Use_Redirect_Domains_Instead)

Comment: hmm just re-read your question, do you actually own both sites? Sounds a bit fishy to me, I would even say you're trying to create a phishing site....naughty naughty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both sites are on the same server, you could setup your virtual host for `example.com` to have as `DocumentRoot` the path to your `cleaning.com/welcome` directory. How you accomplish this depends on your webserver. On apache, this would be something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #rest of config
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/cleaning.com/web/"
    ServerName www.cleaning.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #rest of config
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/cleaning.com/web/example"
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If they aren't on the same server, you could use (I don't believe I'm saying this) framesets.

PS: framesets are obsolete on HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript with jQuery to do this with code if you want.  This way you do not have to alter your web server configuration.  See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seMUj/1/.  Although I agree with the comments above, you shouldn't do that.

HTML:

```
<div style="height:100%" id="a"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$('#a').html('<object style="width:100%;height:100%" data="http://saltwatertides.com/">');​
```